# Equivalent for find -o (shell) in .cmd

Tags: linux, windows, shell, command-line

Can someone tell me the .cmd equivalent command for the shell command find  -o -samefile  ?

I am trying to loop inside folders to copy files into a different location.

My original shell script is : 
for qapi_file in `find . -type d -iname qapi_export -o -samefile qapi/common -o -samefile core/api`; do cp -p $qapi_file/qapi*.h include/qapi/

I have tried doing this:
FOR  /d %%i IN ( DIR -i qapi_export qapi\common\ core\api) do (xcopy /O %i%\qapi*.h include\qapi)

this does not work as I expect it to. If I use **for /d** , it loops once and returns no files to copy. On the other hand if I use **for /r** the for loop becomes endless and I am unable to break the loop (I tried using goto :eof for this but it gives an error - goto was unexpected here)

I am pretty new to this and am unsure how to proceed further. I would appreciate any input in this regard

Answer (score 0):

Using %%i instead of %i% and looping through all subdirectories with /r will do the trick:

```
for /r . %%i in (.) do (
  xcopy /y/o %%i\qapi_export\qapi*.h include\qapi
  xcopy /y/o %%i\qapi\common\qapi*.h include\qapi
  xcopy /y/o %%i\core\api\qapi*.h    include\qapi
) >nul
```